# How can I make a good use of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in Appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I want to extract some data from the server or database, now I'm confusing if I have to put the extracting code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()` function or put the code in `viewdidload()` function in the first viewcontroller. What's the execution efficiency of both methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It depends on your requirement.** If you want the data before actually going to a viewController then you can extract it in didFinishLaunching WithOptions. But if you want the data for only viewController then its good practise to extract it when you are on that viewController i.e in viewDidLoad of that viewController.

Answer (score 0):

If you fetch data over the network, I'd definitely recommend *not* to use `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Any blocking code in this method will prevent the app's UI from loading, so you can't even display a "Please wait" message to the user. Also, iOS will kill your app if `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` blocks for too long (I think the timeout is about 10 seconds).

So either perform the loading in your main view controller, or run it asynchronously in a background queue — in this case, you can of course also put the code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.